# Как в Java рисовать гладкие диагональные линии?

Tags: java, графика, awt

Возможно ли в Java (использую библиотеку awt) рисовать диагональные линии, да и другие фигуры, гладкими линиями? То есть, без видимых пиксельных квадратиков.

На изображении видно что диагональные линии идут, как бы лесенкой, а необходимо, чтобы они были "гладкими".

[image: пример]

Answer (score 7):

В данном случае нужно унаследоваться от  класса **Component** и переопределить метод **paint(Graphics g)** следующим образом:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

//сглаживание: делает графику в Swing более красивой
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; //преобразуем Graphics в Graphics2D
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); //сглаживание
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

}
```

Это сделает графику в **Swing** более привлекательной, без лесенок и пиксельных квадратиков.

Только не забудьте потом "прикрепить" класс, который отрисовывает компоненты, на сам фрейм.

Допустим, это можно сделать в конструкторе:

```
public class FrameCreator extends Component{

  JFrame frame;
 //код...

 public FrameCreator(){
 frame = new JFrame();
 //код...
 frame.add(this); //позволяет прикрепить на фрейм класс, который рисует элементы

 }

}
```

Comment: Такой способ уже пробовал, но при нем сглаживание не идеальное. "Лесенка" все равно видна. Разница только в том, что границы ступенек стали мутнее.

Comment: Ну как мне кажется, для Swing это уже предел. Библиотека написана достаточно давно, а если вы хотите что-то более мощное, то используйте javaFX (в IntelijIdea эта библиотека уже загружена).